# Problem Installing Ubuntu Alongside Windows 10 Pro

Tags: boot, windows-10

My PC originally came with Windows 7(HP). Since then I upgraded to Windows 8 and then to 8.1 Pro. I had also, many times, installed Ubuntu alongside Win8 & 8.1 using various methods (flash drive, wubi, DVD). 
A few weeks ago I Installed Windows 10 and since then I am trying to install a Linux distro. I have even used Universal USB Installer and Rufus Installer. I have changed my BIOS boot priority and Hard Drive boot priority as I did in the past BUT still it seems it doesn't boot from usb. It did only one time and it displayed a message about PXE ROM ..smth.
SO how can I install Linux again on my PC??
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

On most laptops and pre-built machines that come with windows 8 and above, they've removed the option to hit a key during post to open the boot menu. In order to get to it now (although I'm sure there's a way to re-enable it) you need to do the following to open the boot menu:
(this is for windows 10)

Go to the `Settings` menu

Go to the `Recovery` tab

Under `Advanced Startup` click `Restart Now`

Your computer will restart and a menu you pop up instead of the usual login screen

Hit `Troubleshoot`

Hit `Advanced Options`

Hit `Startup Settings`

Hit `F10` to get more options

Hit `F1` to launch recovery environment, aka the boot menu.

Alternatively, you can use command prompt and type `shutdown.exe /r /o` to get to that same blue menu

not sure if this is the problem you were having, but hopefully this helps